# What does it mean to say that a particular mathematical theory is a foundation for mathematics?

Tags: logic, soft-question, category-theory, set-theory, foundations

We usually hear that set theory is a foundation for contemporary mathematics. Category theory is also another foundation of maths. There are other theories which deemed to be a foundation for maths.

> **Question 1:** What does it mean to say a particular theory is a *foundation* of contemporary maths, "precisely"?
>
> **Question 2:** In some cases people say, set theory is a foundation for *almost* all parts of modern mathematics. Why *almost* not *all*? Is there any mathematical concept or field that is not known to be expressible in terms of set theoretic axioms?
>
> **Question 3:** Is it possible that a particular theory be a foundation of *contemporary* maths but not a foundation for mathematics in future? If yes, how is it possible?
>
> **Question 4:** Is it meaningful to compare two foundations of maths and conclude that one of them is *better*, *more useful* or *more fundamental* than the other? If yes, how? and what can we say about the case of set theory and category theory?

Comment: The main problem of set theory is ontology. That's why people want a more natural way of thinking about the objects treated in math (for instance, homotopy type theory). Furthermore, there is no universe in set theory.

Comment: @user40276, no universe in ZFC. Other set theories have universe.

Comment: @user40276 Regarding Martín's comment please see [Quine's New Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) set theory, NF.

Comment: I recently followed an interesting thread by the Univalent foundation program "developers", where they have some communication trouble over foundations being interpreted as *tool with which we develop and implement other mathematical frameworks* vs. *framework which we use to judge other frameworks, demonstrate consistency etc.*. I think the second question is technical in nature and the third and fourth crumble over the fuzziness which comes with the first. I'm going to be so bold and say that there will not be a best one - there's always place for improvement to this and that application.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, I know. I was assuming $text{ZF}$.

Comment: @Martín: Do note, however, that the consistency strength of $\sf NF$ is not expected to exceed that of $\sf PA$. This makes a relatively weak foundations if you want to actually talk about stronger theories.

Comment: @user40276: Other than having a well-defined set complement, of what use is a set universe? (I'm really asking, other than the fact this is counterintuitive at the beginning, I could never find anything a set universe would be useful for.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I was thinking in NBG.

Comment: @Martín: Then this is not quite correct, since the class of all sets is a class, sure, but the collection of all classes is not a class. So it's not quite "the universe of the model" (since the classes do matter.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila category theory (and things relating accessibility) requires universes to work properly...

Comment: @user40276: You're confusing Tarski-Grothendieck universes (or in set theoretic terms, inaccessible cardinals) with the notion of a set universe. Note that $\sf NF$, as mentioned, has a set of all sets, it won't make it easier to talk about large categories and so on, because classes are still not sets. What you are talking about is the fact that you don't have a typed hierarchy of sets, classes, 2-classes, and so on. And that can indeed be solved by adding the axiom that there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals, to serve as "universes". But your comment *is* confusing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, true. But at least all the classes are *subclasses* of $V$. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh! You mean set universe, I thought you said that there is no use of a universe. Anyway, even in this case, in homotopy type theory there is the universe type that is an universal bundle (every construction arises from a pullback of it), maybe trying copying this with a universe in set theory would be a good stuff...

Comment: @user40276 can you elaborate a bit on problem with ontology of set theory?

Comment: @Trismegistos I'm not exactly suited to talk about this aspect. I    think this is related to the word "collection" and its meaning (a collection of collection would contain what's inside the latter collection). Other problem is the fact that, a symbol, for instance "+" will be some set and this does not capture the meaning of this object. Furthermore, there is the fact that a model for set theory is something quite arbitrary (there are a lot of models) viewing set theory as an axiomatic system without a "canonical" interpretation .

Comment: @Trismegistos By canonical interpretation I mean somewhere where the object set exist and not anything that satisfies the axioms. This problem can be, at least partially, solved using second order set theory, because the models are only the $V_{\kappa}$ for $\kappa$ strongly innacesible.

Answer (score 7):

That's an interesting question!

For sure there is not *the* answer, and I guess my opinion will also change  (and hopefully, at some point, converge) during through forthcoming discussions and other answers, but here's a first try which fits with my experience.

> **Proposal for the definition of *foundational system:***
>
> The underlying datum of a *foundational system* should include the following:
>
> - A collection of *syntactic entities* (e.g. formulas, proof trees) and relations between them (e.g. well-formedness of formulas or proof trees).
> - *Translations* from mathematical concepts (e.g. objects, statements, proofs) into syntactic objects and from judgements about them (e.g. "Proposition $A$ is provable" or "$P$ proves proposition $A$"") into statements about relations between the associated syntactic objects.
>
> This datum should ideally be
>
> - *sufficiently expressive:* All mathematical concepts, ideas and judgements should have a translation.
> - *sufficiently meaningful:* 'Most' of what can be expressed through the system in terms of the syntactic entities and their relations should have an intuitive meaning, *and translation should preserve that meaning*.

The last part of the second conditions rules out trivial "foundational systems" with constant translations.

*Examples*

1) *(ZFC) Set theory*. This seems to mostly satisfy the expressiveness condition, but not the property of being sufficiently meaningful:

- *Sufficiently expressive:* To my knowledge, ZFC is sufficiently expressive to allow for the formalization of all mathematics which is in no need of treating classes as first-'class' objects. Category theory however can only be treated on the level of metatheorems, replacing statements like 'For every category ${\mathcal C}$ ...' by a meta-theoretical quantification over FOL formulas in one free variables satisfying the axioms of a category. This has a remedy by considering ZFC + U(niverses). I never encountered some idea or concept I would have liked to formalize but couldn't in ZFC + U.

  This addresses also your second and third question. It is also conceivable that at some point it will become common to add even stronger set theoretic statements to the standard set of axioms. For example, there is Vopenka's principle having very pleasant categorical consequences (see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s+principle).
- *Sufficiently meaningful:* In my opinion, *not at all*: For example, you can ask the ill-posed question as to what the intersection of two arbitrary sets is. For example: what is the intersection of $\text{sin}$ and $\pi$? Sure, intuitively this is nonsense, but nevertheless we can ask and even answer this, provided we settled on some explicit construction of the reals.

2) *Category Theoretical foundations*, for example Lawvere's [E]lementary [T]heory of the [C]ategory of [S]ets, corrects, in my opinion, the latter deficiency of set theory: For example, it is not imposed that any two sets have something to do with each other; instead we may only form their intersection ( in the form of a pullback) provided they both come equipped with a monomorphism into some common third object. I'm not sure but concerning the expressiveness I think ETCS + Universes is as expressive as ZFC.

However, as I'm writing this, I get aware that despite the above suggests that ETCS meets the proposed requirements of a foundational system better than ZFC does, I still tend to think in ZFC instead of ETCS. Apart from habit, that might be because translation of concepts into ETCS is sometimes not as straightforward as it is in ZFC, so maybe this should be a criterion as well?

Please don't get me wrong - I'm not at all meaning to downgrade ZFC with the above, but I only want to note that its expressive power and flexibility comes at the cost of the presence of meaningless statements as well.

Comment: +1. I prefer working in ETCS instead of ZFC, even if not explicitly, since basically you may use the same language, but only that nonsense-stuff (intersections of two arbitrary sets, for example) disappears :).

Comment: Those statements aren’t meaningless; they just aren’t at all interesting.

Comment: I completely agree with the "Sufficiently meaningful" section. The exact same thought has always been at the back of my mind, thanks for allowing me to fully acknowledge it consciously :-)

Comment: If I recall correctly, $\sf ETCS$ is equivalent to $\sf ZC$, rather than $\sf ZFC$. So $\sf ETCS$ per se is weaker. I'm not 100% sure what happens when you add universes to $\sf ETCS$, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably not one definition of "foundation" that everybody will agree on. However, there *is* an answer to the question why **set theory** lies at the foundation of all of mathematics:

Set theory is an extension of propositional logic, the framework of strict reasoning implicitly underlying everything mathematicians do. Let $P$ and $Q$ be propositions, and let $A$ and $B$ be the sets of entities for which propositions $P$ and $Q$ hold. One can now put all boolean operations on $P,Q$ in direct correspondence with set operations on $A,B$, for example

$$P∨ Q\quad\leftrightarrow\quad A∪B$$

$$P∧ Q\quad\leftrightarrow\quad A∩B$$

$$¬ P\quad\leftrightarrow\quad \overline A$$

etc.

*The key advantage of the set-theoretic formulation of logic is that its elements (sets) can be objects that are of mathematical interest anyway*, such as numbers. Thus set theory blurs the distinction between object of study and method of study and provides a natural foundation for such branches of mathematics as algebra, probability theory and topology.

Comment: *It rains.* What is the set underlying that proposition? Is set theory the framework underlying question of computational complexity of different [sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) algorithms. Also, what is the action of a group element, really?

Comment: The *semantics* of a proposition, such as "It rains", are not subject to the methods of standard propositional logic either. You can of course take the set of all days where it rains, but this set will not tell you any more about whether a statement about rain is actually true than boolean algebra will, unless for example you have another set of "days with dry streets" and know their intersection is empty.